# how to handle paypal notify url in our site?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I have paypal form which will have ipn notify url. i have setup notify url in my paypal ipn settings. but it doesn't return to my site. after analyzed for more than 2 days. i found that my controller construct itself i check for current user session exist or not? should i remove the session check in construct not to check for session. Please advise on this. 
this is my code. i am using codeigniter application.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();


    $this->load->model('user_model');
    // if (!isEmployee()) {
//           redirect('information');
 //          
//       }
}

 function paypal_ipn(){


    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data =  array("paypal_transaction_id"=>$txn_id);
    $this->db->insert("payments",$data);

    }
```

I have commented out now

Answer (score 0):

Notify url is part of the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) mechanism of PayPal. This URL is called by PayPal to notify about a payment. It is not part of the user session at all so do not check for it.

I recommend you to read the documentation and get the example from here:
[documentation IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/)